# How can I using getrlimit to get normal user's nproc in c program

Tags: c, system-calls, ulimit, setuid

```
[root@api ~]# ulimit -u
3766
```

```
[zack@api ~]$ ulimit -u
5000
```

i cant fetch zack's nproc by using setuid(zackid)  in program ,why?

```
[root@api dbhome]# ./a zack
UID:1000
EUID:1000
GID:1000
RLIMIT_NPROC cur:3766 // still root's nproc
```

Comment: Setting those limits is part of setting up the user session. Usually this is configured via PAM. Dropping the privileges to a specific user does not necessarily mean the ulimit settings for that user are applied.

Comment: I guess `./a` is the binary you have created? If so, what does it exactly do?

Comment: `in program` In what program? Show sources.

Comment: if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC,&r)<0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"getrlimit error\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("RLIMIT_NPROC cur:%d\n",r.rlim_cur);                                                                               this is what a do . i execute a by using user "root",but i wangt to get the limits info of the user "zack"